# boost::asio::udp::socket::async_receive_from() seems to corrupt incoming data under certain circumstances

Tags: boost-asio

I'm not gonna post any real code here, because it's a part of a complex code base, but I'll ask anyway just in case somebody find this issue familiar:

I create a boost::asio::io_service and run it in a boost::thread.

Then I use boost::asio::udp::socket::async_receive_from() to wait for incoming packet.
The call looks like this:

```
udpSocket.async_receive_from(
        inDataBuffer,
        udpEndpoint,
        boost::bind(    &Node::handleReceiveFrom, this,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
        )
```

The signature of handleReceiveFrom() is this:

```
void Node::handleReceiveFrom( const boost::system::error_code& errc, size_t bytesRecvd )
```

Inside handleReceiveFrom(), I access the inDataBuffer passed to async_receive_from() and read bytesRecvd bytes from it. But sometimes when the packets arrive really fast, the bytesRecvd value refers to the size of the packet before the one that's actually found in the inDataBuffer.

Precisely, the packet whose size is found in bytesRecvd never actually appears in inDataBuffer, at least not as fat as handleReceiveFrom() can see, and instead, the data of the next packet is in the inDataBuffer by the time handleReceiveFrom() gets a chance to look at it.

I thought the problem was that I was somehow calling async_receive_from() from two different threads but after some testing, that doesn't seem to be the case.

Apart from that, I'm at a loss what could be going on here.

I would very much appreciate any thought on this!

Comment: Just a comment to say that I see this exact problem on Win10, Boost 1.77. From my sending app, if I send two different packets right after each other, then partway through my receive handler the buffer gets overwritten with the second packet, but then the handler gets called again for the second packet. If I insert a small delay between packets being sent, this problem is greatly reduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the root cause of the problem but I solved it by using the synchronous Asio receive function instead of the asynchronous one. In other words, I ditched boost::asio::udp::socket::async_receive_from() and replaced it with boost::asio::udp::socket::receive_from() run in a separate thread.

This way, I actually implemented what I *thought* asio was doing when I called async_receive_from(). But apparently, there's something inside that routine that works in a different way than I'd expect.

Still, this solution works like a charm, so I'm declaring my previous question closed.